# W3C Validator error: Parse Error opacity=60

Tags: html, css

I've run a stylesheet through the CSS validator at W3C... The only error I get is 
"Parse Error Opacity=60"
It's in this bit of the CSS:

```
/*Navigation Link styling */
#Nav a:link, a:visited {
display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #99FFFF;
text-align: center;
padding:5px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
opacity:0.6;
```

}

I'm assuming that the validator isn't happy with the "filter:alpha(opacity=60);" part - Is this just because it is not a standard function? And can this error be ignored.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is a non-standard property used by Microsoft (the SVG working group is reusing the name so it may appear in a new specification, but that will be a completely different thing). The error can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It's not standard CSS, no. It can be ignored if it's doing what you want it to do and you're not bothered about validating your CSS.